# Need help on understanding why this code doesn't compile

Tags: java, syntax, type-conversion, operands

> What is the data type of x + y?
>
> double x = 39.21;
>
> float y = 2.1;
>
> *Explanation:*
>
> This is actually a trick question, as this code will not compile! As
>   you may remember from Chapter 1,  floating-point literals are assumed
>   to be double, unless postfixed with an f, as in 2.1f. If the value was
>   set properly to 2.1f, then the promotion would be similar to the last
>   example, with both operands being promoted to a double, and the result
>   would be a double value.
>
> But I don't understand. If float y = 2.1; was assumed to be double
>   there would be no need for the promotion of variable y to the double.
>   And I'm more confused by the next problem, which is:
>
> What is the data type of x * y / z?
>
> short x = 14; float y = 13; double z = 30;

The book says this will compile even the float y = 13; is not float y = 13f. Do I only add f next to the float number if they are decimal? I really can't see the difference between this problem and aforementioned problem.

Comment: y is allocated as a float. The literal expression "2.1" (without an explicit trailing f) is a double. It won't compile because you can't stuff a larger double into a smaller float.

Comment: You can, however, assign an int `13` into a float, because an int can be promoted to a float.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361456/why-explicit-type-casting-required-from-double-to-float-but-not-from-int-to-byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring `char`, Java will *promote* numeric types like this:

```
byte > short > int > long > float > double
```

These are called *widening conversions*. See JLS [§5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) for detail.

Binary operators will promote to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`, whichever is nearest from the two values of the operator, i.e. result will never be `byte` or `short`. Example: `byte + short` will promote both sides to `int`. See JLS [§5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) for detail.

The assignment operator will also do *widening conversion* of the value, with the extra rule that a *constant expression* of type `byte`, `short`, or `int` will go through a [*narrowing conversion*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) if the type of the variable is `byte` or `short`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type. Note, there is no rule for narrowing `double` constant to `float`. See JLS [§5.2. Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) for detail.

So, for your code:

```
double x = 39.21; // double constant  to  double  (identity conversion)
float y = 2.1; // fails because double constant cannot promote to float
```

*If* code had compiled, what is the data type of `x + y`?

```
x + y  // double + float  promotes to  double
```

Answer: `double`

Next part:

```
short x = 14;  // narrowing conversion of  int constant  to  short
float y = 13;  // widening conversion of  int constant  to  float
double z = 30; // widening conversion of  int constant  to  double
```

Now, what is the data type of `x * y / z`?

```
x * y        // short * float  promotes to  float
(x * y) / z  // (float) / double  promotes to  double
```

Answer: `double`

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you cannot initialize a float(with a double value) as a double value. Using the `2.1f` initializes that value as a float. So you would need `y = 2.1f`. You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369726/declaring-floats-why-default-type-double)

For the second question, the reason this works is the float is an integer (13) which can be promoted to type float.

Comment: *"the float is an integer"*? Did you mean "the *value* is an integer"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/787195/7750124), if you do not specify the character 'f' after the digits, the value will be treated as a double.

With that said, the piece of code below will compile but only if the character 'f' is added to the end of the floating point value.

```
double x = 7.0;
float y = 2.0f;
System.out.print(x + y);
```

Comment: You are correct, I have miss interpreted my understanding.  Excuse me for this.

Comment: But if the value of y is treated as a double, then shouldn't x+y still work since it's double + double?

Comment: @MadPhysicist answer correctly explains it.