# Cannot convert from double to float Error

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I'm writing a simple program that converts pounds to kilos, but I'm a bit confused

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FiveTenOne {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard =  new Scanner(System.in); //Creates Scanner Object

        System.out.print("Enter your weight in pounds: ");

        float pounds = keyboard.nextFloat();

        float kilos = pounds / 2.2;

        System.out.print("Your value in kilos is: " + kilos);

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

This is the code I wrote, all variables have been set to floats, yet it tells me that it cant convert from a double. at "pounds / 2.2;"

However when I write it like the code below "(float) (pounds / 2.2)" then no error comes back

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FiveTenOne {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard =  new Scanner(System.in); //Creates Scanner Object

        System.out.print("Enter your weight in pounds: ");

        float pounds = keyboard.nextFloat();

        float kilos = (float) (pounds / 2.2);

        System.out.print("Your value in kilos is: " + kilos);

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the first code doesn't take it as a float?

or is it an IDE problem?

I tried both ways and know that the second one works fine, but I want to understand why exactly the first one doesn't work

Comment: Write 2.2 as 2.2f, so it is a float. No casting needed.

Comment: `2.2` is a `double` (not a `float`) and if one of the operands is `double`, the result will be `double` - explained in the Java Language Specification [5.6. Numeric Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6). See also [3.10.2. Floating-Point Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float` is, at this point, best thought of as a historic abberation. Do not use them; there is no need. `double` is like float but more precise, and just as fast if not faster. Also, java is designed to prefer them, so simple constants such as `2.2` are actually considered a double. Hence, `aFloatValue / 2.2` is a float divided by a double, which java solves by first silently upgrading the float to a double, then doing double division. This produces a `double` value. Which you try to assign to a variable of type `float` which is risky (can remove detail - a so called 'narrowing conversion'), which requires an explicit cast so you, the programmer, can tell the compiler: Yes. yes, I heard you, this is dangerous, I know what I'm doing shut up and compile my code please.

The correct answer here is to get rid of all mention of the word `float` and use `double` everywhere. You lose nothing, and your code is simpler; no casts would be needed then.

Answer (score 1):

Double and Float are the datatypes in java, so to convert from one type to the other you have to cast it .
For example ,  `pounds/2.2` returns a double value ( one class ) say 20.0.
To convert it we have to cast into Float which is `20f`.

Comment: “`pounds/2.2` returns a double value” This would be a much better answer if you explained why that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

`double` and `float` are different data types, see e.g. [Java: double vs float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787181/java-double-vs-float). The error message says that the division `pounds / 2.2` returns a `double` value. If you want the result to be `float`, the value has to be cast to `float` explicitly, just like you did in your second code example.

Comment: please do not confuse `double` - a primitive - with `Double` - a wrapper class!